# How to check if profile images exist else use fallback jpg in a react App

Tags: reactjs

I am displaying search results in a React App. The file `img src={`/users/${id}/avatar.jpg`}` does not exist for all users. The user's gender is available in the field `$gender`. If they do not have an avatar.jog uploaded, I want to use male.jpg for gender=male and female.jpg for gender=female.

Below is the component code:

```
          import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import AppLink from '../../others/link/link'

    class SearchResult extends Component {

                    </span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="mb1">
                          <span><span className="text-bold">Gender: src here</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>

            </div>
          )
        }
    }

    export default SearchResult
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic for determining a user's profile images might be better placed in your backend, so that your overall design for fetching and displaying avatar images is simpler an more robust.

If a user has not uploaded an avatar image, the server can decied what image to serve for that user by the user's `id` (ie  to serve an avatar if one has been uploaded, or serve a gender image as a fallback). That saves potential issues in your front end code (ie valid client side user data, but no avatar image on server, causing image not found error).

If however, you know that an avatar exists when say, the users `id` is defined, then the following might might your requirements:

```
class SearchResult extends Component {
  render() {
    let {
      id,
      username,
      firstname,
      surname,
      gender
    } = this.props

    // Determine the avatarImage path depending on the existance of a valid 
    // user id. If user id is invalid, fallback to an image based on gender
    const avatarImage = (id !== undefined && id !== null) ? 
    `/users/${id}/avatar.jpg` : `/${ gender }.jpg`

    return (
      <div className="user_item">
        <div className="user-container">
          <div className="user-l">
            <div className="text-center">
              <AppLink url={`/profile/${username}`}>

                {/* Apply the computed avatarImage to the img element /*}
                <img src={ avatarImage } className="user_avatar" />

              </AppLink>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="user-m half-container">
            <div className="halfL">
              <div className="mb1">
                <AppLink
                  url={`/profile/${username}`}
                  className="lead m2 s_userName"
                  label={username}
                />
              </div>
              <span>{firstname} {surname}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="halfR">
              <div className="mb1">
                <span>
                  <span className="text-bold">Age:</span> {age}
                </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="mb1">
                      <span><span className="text-bold">Gender:</span> {gender}</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>

            <div className="mb1">
              <AppLink
                url={`/profile/${username}`}
                className="btn btn-sm"
                label={`Contact ${username}`}
              />
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
}

export default SearchResult
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The id will always exist. If the user has uploaded an avatar, I am storing it in the user's folder. So checking if id exists will not work. As mentioned in my question - `The file img src={/users/${id}/avatar.jpg} does not exist for all users`

Comment: Are you providing any way for the client app to determine if `avatar.jpg` is present for a user on the backend?

Comment: No, I am just letting them upload an image that goes straight into a folder named with their id.. For example user 456's image will be saved in a folder named 456 as avatar.jpg .. This is the first time I am thinking a database column with avatar would have been good. Without that I have to check if file in folder exists ..

Comment: Yes - alternatvily the component could also attempt to fetch the avatar image and if that fails, fallback to a gender avatar, however that's probably not desirable. If you'd like me to show you how that could be achieved, let me know and I'll update the answer

Comment: Yes please, I would like to know how it can be done. I am able to load a generic image called user.jpg (please see question) but not a gender specific image. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Kal , I've added another answer demonstrating another strategy to deal with these constraints - see below, hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not an ideal solution (as identified above, you should be storing the user's avatar state in your database), however it shows a strategy to resolve the user avatar from the client in order to achieve what you're after.

In short, this approach will issue a request to your back-end to see if the user's avatar image exists on the server. If the request is successful, that avatar image url is stored in the component and used for subsequent rendering.
If the request fails, the component applies the "fallback" behaviour - that is, it will use the input props to deduce the "gender" image, similar to that shown above.

See `[UPDATED]` tags below for relevant additions from your current code:

```
class SearchResult extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    /* [UPDATED] Setup the default userImage to be initially displayed */
    this.state = {
       userImage : `/images/users.jpg`
    }
  }

  /* [UPDATED] When the component is mounted, use the id and gender props
     to decide which image to display for the user
  */
  componentDidMount() {

    const { id, gender } = this.props
    const avatarImage = `/users/${id}/avatar.jpg`

    /* [UPDATED] Query the server for the user's avatar - if the query 
       succeeds then use the avatar image, otherwise fallback to gender 
       image. In either case, the userImage is stored in the components 
       state
    */
    fetch(avatarImage).then(response => {
      if(!response.ok) {
        this.setState({ userImage : `/${ gender }.jpg` })
      }
      else {
        this.setState({ userImage : `/users/${id}/avatar.jpg` })
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    let {
      id,
      username,
      firstname,
      surname,
      gender
    } = this.props

    {/* [UPDATED] Extract userImage from state /*}
    const { userImage } = this.state

    return (
      <div className="user_item">
        <div className="user-container">
          <div className="user-l">
            <div className="text-center">
              <AppLink url={`/profile/${username}`}>

                {/* [UPDATED] Apply the userImage to the img element based on state /*}
                <img src={ userImage } className="user_avatar" />

              </AppLink>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="user-m half-container">
            <div className="halfL">
              <div className="mb1">
                <AppLink
                  url={`/profile/${username}`}
                  className="lead m2 s_userName"
                  label={username}
                />
              </div>
              <span>{firstname} {surname}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="halfR">
              <div className="mb1">
                <span>
                  <span className="text-bold">Age:</span> {age}
                </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="mb1">
                      <span><span className="text-bold">Gender:</span> {gender}</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>

            <div className="mb1">
              <AppLink
                url={`/profile/${username}`}
                className="btn btn-sm"
                label={`Contact ${username}`}
              />
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
}

export default SearchResult
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: First, thanks for taking time for this answer, I dont know why its not working but the response.ok is always true and it always tries to load `/users/${id}/avatar.jpg`.. I have the code like you posted.

Comment: I route the user to a custom error page using a Switch in my App routes.

Comment: I could not make anything work so I had to compromise and create a generic image that says "No Photo" and use it for both genders.. I just used   addDefaultSrc to render the common default image. Thanks for the answers though !

Comment: I took your advice and I created a new column in the database called avatar. I update it to Y as soon as an avatar is uploaded.

Comment: Hi @Kal that's great - did you need any more help with this problem?

Comment: No, it was too easy when I have a database column to query against. I have to find all folders out of 17 thousand that have an image in them and update the database column.. Can I send you question in future if I hit any react issues? I will mark this accepted.

Comment: Hi @Kal that is great to hear that it worked for you in the end - yes by all means please feel free to ask me questions and either I or someone else from the community should be able to help you :-)